# What's the difference between 「お昼前」 and 「午前」?

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

Is there any difference between 「お昼前」 and 「午前」 in both meanings and the circumstances used?

The same question for 「お昼過ぎ」 and 「午後」.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When it's not lunchtime yet but you start to feel a little hungry, you call it お昼前. That's my "gut" feeling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

午前 (=a.m.) refers to 12 hours from midnight to noon. Likewise, 午後 (=p.m.) refers to 12 hours from noon to midnight.

お昼前 refers to a short period before noon. When お昼前 starts is not strictly defined, but 9:00 is probably not お昼前 and 10:30 is probably お昼前. Likewise, 昼過ぎ refers to one or two hours just after noon.